# Get Price For Configurable Product Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I m working on ../Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml. I already write onsale label for products like this;

```
<span class="onsale">
    <span>
     <?php
     $label_price=$_product->getPrice();
     $final_price=$_product->getSpecialPrice();
     $save_percent = 100 - round(($final_price / $label_price)*100);
     echo $save_percent.'% Off';?>
    </span>
</span>
```

Its working perfect for Simple product but its not working for configurable products, I know configurable products doesn't have price but how can I get configurable first child product price or get price which is show as default price.

Comment: hope this will help you to get childs products price.. [child products of configurable product](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117783/getting-simple-products-from-configurable)

Comment: I already read that one and tried but 'getUsedProducts($_product);' giving an error. That answer didnt work for me.

Comment: You can get $_product->getFinalPrice() for config product, You have got display price of product

Comment: Have you checked using i have mentioned method above?

Comment: Thank you man it worked but that one screwed simple product I solved it with basic if else. I ll add answer maybe someone else need it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added to the answer for others. Only note is, if you try getFinalPrice(); for simple product it will be same results with getSpecialPrice(); that reason I m checking type.

```
<span class="onsale">
<span>
<?php
    //echo $_product->getTypeId();
    if($_product->getTypeId()!="simple"){
        $label_price=$_product->getSpecialPrice();
        $final_price=$_product->getFinalPrice();
        $save_percent = 100 - round(($final_price / $label_price)*100);
        echo $save_percent.'% Off';
    }else{

        $label_price=$_product->getPrice();
        $final_price=$_product->getSpecialPrice();
        $save_percent = 100 - round(($final_price / $label_price)*100);
        echo $save_percent.'% Off';

    }
    ?>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: For configurable product, which price it would get for final price

Comment: very bad answer, it not works

Answer (score 1):

Head to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257587/magento-2-how-to-get-final-price-original-price-of-all-types-of-product#258705), which explains how to get the pricing of all types of products in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the

```
prcingHelper (Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data)
```

instead of calculating the price via

```
round () - 100 * 100 etc.
```

to prevent rounding errors.

Answer (score -1):

> vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Price.php

```
public function getPrice($product)
    {
       if ($product->getCustomOption('simple_product')) {
            return $product->getCustomOption('simple_product')->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
        } else {
            return $product->getFinalPrice();  
        }
    }
```