# Magento 2 : How to get Final price & Original price of all types of product

Tags: magento2, frontend, products, special-price, product-prices

How can I get **Original price** and **Final price** of given below types product?

1. Simple product
2. Configurable product
3. Bundle product
4. Group product

For **simple product** I can get price easily using below code.

```
$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
$originalPrice = $product->getPrice();
```

But I am not able to get **Original price** and **Final price** for **Configurable product**, **Bundle product**, **Group product**

Is there any easy way to get both prices of all other types of product.

---

**EDIT :**

I get price **Original price** and **Final price** of configurable product using below code. and take reference from [get-price-range-configurable-product-magento-2](https://webkul.com/blog/get-price-range-configurable-product-magento-2/)

```
$basePrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');

$regularPrice = $basePrice->getMinRegularAmount()->getValue();
$specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: you can get original price and final price here <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory'); $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create(); $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); $collection->addWebsiteFilter(); $collection->addMinimalPrice(); $collection->addFinalPrice(); $collection->addStoreFilter(); $collection->setVisibility($objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds()); ?> <?php foreach ($collecti

Comment: Have you checked this code? is it working?
It is not working for me.

Comment: yes this code working for me

Comment: `$_product->getSpecialPrice();` is not working for me

Comment: `if($orgprice > $specialprice){
echo $_product->getSpecialPrice();
}`

Comment: kindly check my updated question, now i am able to get price of `config product` & `simple product`

i can't get for `groupe product` & `bundle product`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can get **Regular price** and **Final price** of all types of product using below way.

> 1. Simple Product

```
$regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
$specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
```

> 2. Configurable product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
      $basePrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');

      $regularPrice = $basePrice->getMinRegularAmount()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
}
```

> 3. Bundle product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
      $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();            
}
```

> 4. Group product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
      $usedProds = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);            
      foreach ($usedProds as $child) {
          if ($child->getId() != $product->getId()) {
                $regularPrice += $child->getPrice();
                $specialPrice += $child->getFinalPrice();
          }
      }
}
```

**Note :** In above example **$product** is current product.

Comment: So you cannot get the minimal price based on special price of a bundled product? I get that will be the same as a "final_price" however in some cases catalog price rules may be the cause of the discount to the final price and not the "special price" set at product level and would like a way to differentiate?