# Magento 2 - get final prices include tax and round

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, layout, magento2.2

I've custom block phtml in my old store and I need to be converted to Magento 2.

**Magento 1.9.x code:**

```
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
$unitPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency(round($_finalPriceInclTax / $_product->getHedNetWeight(), 2),true,false);
```

How can I get Final Price included Tax in Magento 2 and how can I use `Mage::helper('core')->currency(round)` in Magento 2?

I try to display the price like this:

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($finalprice / $HedNetWeight,true,false);
```

Thank you

Comment: Check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257587/magento-2-how-to-get-final-price-original-price-of-all-types-of-product

In above answer i explain to get final price of all types of product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Block :-**

```
protected $priceCurrency;

protected $taxHelper;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $taxHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
){
    $this->taxHelper = $taxHelper;
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
}

public function finalPrice($product) {
    return $this->taxHelper->getTaxPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);
}

public function currency($value, $format = true, $includeContainer = true)
{
    return $format
    ? $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value, $includeContainer)
    : $this->priceCurrency->convert($value);
}
```

**In phtml :-**

```
<?= $block->currency($block->finalPrice(),true,false); ?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but if you read again I need this to be just a simple code in phtml file

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of extensions allows to change or delete the decimal number for the front store.

https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price

Comment: Hi thank you, but I don't need a global solution, I need to remove the decimal numbers only in my code