# Magento 2: existing products doesn't load regular price through a cron job

Tags: magento2, products, cron, magento-cron, factory

Everything was work fine. But now from cron doesn't load productFactory right! Can somebody please help me?

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $_directorylist
) {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->quote = $quote;
    $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
    $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
    $this->_directorylist=$_directorylist;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function exportToCsv($store_id, $store_name)
{
    if(is_null($store_id) || $store_id == '')
    {
        $store_id = 0;
    }
    if(is_null($store_name) || $store_name == '')
    {
        $store_name = 'default';
    }

    $products = $this->productFactory->create()
            ->setStoreId($store_id)
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', '4');
foreach($products as $product)
    {
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
            $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
            $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
        print_r($regularPrice); // this is null
        } }
```

Manually work fine!

```
class Run {
protected $categoryFactory;
protected $_storeManager;
protected $helper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magelan\FacebookAds\Helper\Data $helper
) {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->helper = $helper;
}

public function execute()
{
    $storeManagerDataList = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
    foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
            $this->helper->exportToCsv($key, $value['code']);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Nothing, is just empty(null), I load exportToCsv(0, "default"), but 3days ago was working and nothing change in my code, you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We can debug the cron issue like below.

Download [magerun2](https://files.magerun.net/) by running the below commands in the Magento root folder.

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
```

Then run the below command, it will list all cron jobs.

```
php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list
```

Then run the needed specific cron by job code.

```
php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run [cron code]
```

It will show the detailed error if the cron class having any error. Using these details, we can fix the code issue.

Comment: Thank you, for your help, I discovered that is problem if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
    $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
    $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
   } so regularPrice is empty, you have some suggestions, how can I fix that?

Comment: So something changes on the server or deploy magento and stops working...

Comment: show me the error screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

try below code. use product collection factory and check.

```
protected $_productsCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productsCollectionFactory = $productsCollectionFactory;
    }

 ------------------
    $store_id = 0;
    $collection = $this->_productsCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->->setStoreId($store_id);
```

Comment: I change it, but the same mistake, other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code from this

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
    $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
    $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
}
```

to this

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
      $basePrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');

      $regularPrice = $basePrice->getMinRegularAmount()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
}
```

Why because you are using a simple product code for a configurable product that doesn't hold its own price all you can get a minimum price (start from)

For more follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258705/77554)