# Magento2: How to get simple products Assosiate to configurable products

Tags: magento2, module, configurable-product, custom

I want to get simple products Associate to configurable products in custom module using factory method.
**(not using object manager)**

Comment: Do you mean get simple product list which is assign in configurable products?

Comment: Check 2nd answer in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117783/getting-simple-products-from-configurable

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code using factory method :

```
protected $productFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ....
)
{
   ....
   $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
   ....
}

public function yourFunction()
{
   $configProduct = $this->productFactory->create()->load($product_id);

   $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
   foreach ($_children as $child){
    echo "Simple Product Ids ".$child->getID()."<br/>";
   }
}
```